# applying fixed-width container to a fluid website?

Tags: containers, wrapper, resolution, fixed, fluid

I've got to fix a website, which is developed in html 5 and has structured header, section and footer tag set directly inside the body tag. The site has 100% view on any resolution on desktop.

Now I need to fix the display of website to a particular resolution (say 1024*768 px). For this, I created a new div directly inside the body tag and put all the above three tags i.e. header, section and footer within this. I also defined the fixed value for width in css for newly created div.

However, the site is still displaying on 100% in browser in resolutions above 1024*768. Though I expected it to be bounded within said dimensions on any higher resolution.

I checked inside the css, my class name is unique (as applied on new div). Though there is given a .wrapper class as 100% but didn't find it applied anywhere in html.

Can anyone please help me on this!

Answer (score 1):

Header you are using in  website is at the top of the page you don’t need to position it.

```
#container {

max-width: 1200px;

position: relative;

margin: 0 auto;

}

#header {

position: fixed;

top: 0;

width: 1200px;

max-width: 100%;

}
```